# Django making tons of duplicate queries

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Im working with on an ecommerce project where django is making tons of tons of duplicate queries while fetching products from database using django ORM.

please find the below codes for your reference help to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

**Product model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
variations = (
    ('None', 'None'),
    ('Size', 'Size'),
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
store = models.ManyToManyField(Store)
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=500)
sku = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
tax = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
stock = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
variations = models.CharField(choices=variations, max_length=20)
short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
details = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, 
blank=True)
delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, 
 verbose_name="Delivery Time")
returnable = models.BooleanField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, 
verbose_name="Returnable")
emi = models.BooleanField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="EMI 
available")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', default='product.png', 
null=True, blank=True)
image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_three = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_four = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_five = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
blank=True,
                             related_name='products')
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('Active', 'Active'), ('Inactive', 
'Inactive')))
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                          blank=True)  # This is used only for filtration
color = models.ManyToManyField(Colors)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.pk) + ":" + self.name + ":"

@property
def get_rating(self):
    total = sum(int(review['stars']) for review in 
    self.reviews.select_related('r_product').values())
    return total
```

**Product review class**

```
class ProductReview(models.Model):
r_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='reviews')
review_by = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
related_name='reviews')
stars = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                            validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)]
                            )
notes = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**This is django debug toolbar result**

```
   SELECT "backend_productreview"."id",
   "backend_productreview"."r_product_id",
   "backend_productreview"."review_by_id",
   "backend_productreview"."stars",
   "backend_productreview"."notes",
   "backend_productreview"."date"
  FROM "backend_productreview"
  WHERE "backend_productreview"."r_product_id" = '102'
```

114 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.

**This is query highlighted by django debug toolbar**

```
total = sum(int(review['stars']) for review in 
self.reviews.select_related('r_product').values())
```

Comment: you probably want to use django's `aggregate` to `Sum` the reviews. hHave a look at [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope this will work

```
from django.db.models import Sum
self.reviews.aggregate(Sum('stars'))
# returns {'starts__sum': 1000} for example
```